# Efficient Way to Link and Use External Libraries in C++ with CMake/MakeFiles

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm pretty new to C++ and I've been running into some issues when it comes to using external libraries,especially with tools like CMake or MakeFiles. Take, for instance, when I'm trying to install libraries from GitHub, like dearimgui. These libraries often come with a bunch of other stuff they depend on, and those dependencies might have their own dependencies, making the whole process kind of a headache.

So, I'm hoping to get some advice on the easiest and most reliable way to add external libraries to my C++ projects.

I followed many yts tutorial and I ended up messed up , missing libraries and the code is not running ;-;

Comment: Focus on one specific problem. What specific library you're unable to use? What errors are you getting? What build system are you trying to use?

Comment: get familiar with some package manager: vcpkg, conan, cpm.

Comment: Specifically with dear imgui, this is not distributed as a library, just include the relevant source code files in your application.

Comment: for example: this lib: https://github.com/yourWaifu/sleepy-discord require openssl,cpr,websocket,.... . I have to install it manualy , and it really slow and takes a long time sometimes encountering some errors

Comment: That's ok. Someone who's "pretty new to C++" is not really expected to quickly learn years of programming experience and a wide range of technical knowledge and understanding that's required to be able to immediately know how to grab and install random stuff from github and quickly resolve any minor issues. So, for now, just keep learning the hardest and the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, with your textbook, and focus on learning core C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one single answer that applies to all libraries, but since you mentioned Dear Imgui, I will explain that one.

Dear Imgui has no external dependencies, and according to its documentation is intended to be "vendored" (copied) into your project, or added as a Git submodule (which would be my preference).

From there, you set up CMakeLists.txt to build Dear Imgui's .cpp files the same as you would build any other files in your project.

Comment: like If I install lib on github manually , I may have to install other deps manualy

Comment: @MinhTuệNguyễn: There are no other deps of Dear Imgui.  If you think there are, please say what you think the deps are.  Or maybe you're talking about some other library which was not mentioned in your question?  In which case you should post a new question with the specific, detailed problems you are having.

Comment: just an example , for Dear Imgui in vcpkg ,it  requires many bindings to work properly